# twisted calling getPeerCertificate in connectionMade returns None

Tags: python, ssl, twisted

calling getPeerCertificate in connectionMade in twisted returns None what can i do

```
class Handler(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print self.transport.getPeerCertificate().get_subject().commonName

    def connectionMade(self):
        print self.transport.getPeerCertificate().get_subject().commonName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `getPeerCertificate` in `connectionMade`.  As you have likely observed, it returns a correct certificate if you call it in `dataReceived`.